# USB_HID is not working

Tags: kernel, usb, linux-kernel, drivers

How do I get a usb keyboard to work? I have already selected and compiled the USB HID transport layer and I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you have your other USB stuff right (ehci/uhci, etc):

**Device Drivers -> HID support -> USB HID support -> USB HID Transport Layer**

Comment: already did that

Comment: Ah, so you said, lol.  Well, if you are sure the USB stuff is good and that is selected, it should work...which I am guessing it may be hard to tell if the USB stuff in general works if your keyboard doesn't ;)